Cannot SSH through Remote Network, Only on LAN
I'm trying to SSH remotely into linux machine running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I've set up openssh-server and am able to SSH in when on the same wifi network.
I've set up a DDNS service to point me to the machine when on a remote network. However, whenever I try to SSH in remotely, I get the following error:
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.4
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer 

or
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.4
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

I've set up port forwarding using my router and I'm using port 22.
I've taken a look at firewalls and have disabled ufw with sudo ufw disable and I'm accepting all incoming traffic in iptables with sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT .
Any help would be appreciated.
Edit: Here is the output from iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [29578:27273438]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [17640:2332395]
:ufw-after-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-after-input - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-after-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-before-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-output - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-input - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-output - [0:0]
:ufw-track-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-track-input - [0:0]
:ufw-track-output - [0:0]
COMMIT


It looks like basic connectivity issue. Routes, firewalls, such stuff. Notice that iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT does not accept all incoming traffic, it accepts all traffic that wasn't processed yet upon reaching the end of the chain (sets a "policy"), acting as a last rule in a chain. Traffic still might be dropped by some explicit rule in this or another chain; we need to see a complete firewall (as output by iptables-save) to tell. And, you must examine all firewalls along the path, not only a firewall on a target system.

port 22 may has been disabled by ISP, try to forward another router's port to Ubuntu port 22?
